# Replacing certain part of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a flat file with data in it and have a specific place in each row that I want to :

1. Replace with a currency value(this is a decimal)
2. Make this 2 decimal points and to make 11 characters long.

An example of my data looks like this:

```
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017537400        TUYAU DE FREIN BRAKE HOSE     P70   0000000203300000000000                          00001000000000000520J
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017689400        CYLINDRE ROUE  WHEEL CYLINDER W70   0000000145200000000000                          00001000000000000455K
```

Within this text, I want to replace the text at character 100 which is 11 characters long, with a decimal value that I calculate(This value is a currency value) which I need to convert to cents and then it needs to be a total of 11 characters long.

The part I want to change is after this(This is just so that you can find the spot easily):

```
00000002033
00000001452
```

So in the 2 rows above I want the following results:

```
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017537400        TUYAU DE FREIN BRAKE HOSE     P70   0000000203300000091972                          00001000000000000520J
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017689400        CYLINDRE ROUE  WHEEL CYLINDER W70   0000000145200000065688                          00001000000000000455K
```

This is my result:

```
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017537400        TUYAU DE FREIN BRAKE HOSE     P70   0000000203391972.920000                          0000191972.9200000520J
ALD2018041620180416FRAP   25CEUR  0017689400        CYLINDRE ROUE  WHEEL CYLINDER W70   0000000145265688.480000                          0000165688.4800000455K
```

I am making use of `SUBSTRING` to try and replace at the specific place I want, which works....but it is replacing further on in the text as well, which I don't want it to(Obviously). Also, I dont know how I am going to remove from the decimal to the end(Which seems to always be 7 characters with the decimal point) and then add the correct amount of 0's in front to make the whole length 11 characters.

**EDIT**

I have figured out how to only replace the FIRST occurrence, by replacing :

```
 SET @TextToChange = REPLACE(@TextToChange,SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11),(((CAST(@UnitPurchasePriceexVAT as decimal(11,2))/100) * @ExchangeRate * 100) * @RetailePriceValue)*100)
```

With This:

```
SET @TextToChange = STUFF(@TextToChange, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11), @TextToChange), LEN(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11)), (((CAST(@UnitPurchasePriceexVAT as decimal(11,2))/100) * @ExchangeRate * 100) * @RetailePriceValue)*100)
```

This is the code I am trying:

```
DECLARE @FilePath as Varchar(1000)
DECLARE @TotalRecords as INT
DECLARE @RecordCount AS INT

SET @FilePath = 'C:\Client Files\Client\AP\2018-07-17\AP-XP0006-Test.txt'
DECLARE @UnitPurchasePriceexVAT As Varchar(11)
DECLARE @TextToChange As Varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ExchangeRate as Decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @RetailePriceValue as Decimal(18,4)
SET @ExchangeRate = (SELECT CalcValue FROM CalculationValues WHERE CalcName = 'Exchange Rate')
SET @RetailePriceValue = (SELECT CalcValue FROM CalculationValues WHERE CalcName = 'Retail Price Value')

CREATE TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
(Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

DECLARE @SQL as Varchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'bulk insert #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
from ''' + @FilePath + ''' 
with (fieldterminator = ''\t'', rowterminator = ''0x0a'')'

EXEC (@SQL)

CREATE TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging
(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

 CREATE TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
(Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

INSERT INTO #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging(Text)
SELECT Text FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp

SET @TotalRecords = (SELECT COUNT(TEXT) FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging)
SET @RecordCount = 1

WHILE (@RecordCount <= @TotalRecords)
BEGIN
    SET @TextToChange = (SELECT Text FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging WHERE ID = @RecordCount)

    SET @UnitPurchasePriceexVAT = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,89,11))

    SET @TextToChange = STUFF(@TextToChange, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11), @TextToChange), LEN(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11)), (((CAST(@UnitPurchasePriceexVAT as decimal(11,2))/100) * @ExchangeRate * 100) * @RetailePriceValue)*100)

    INSERT INTO #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
    SELECT @TextToChange

    SET @RecordCount = @RecordCount + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
SELECT * FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
DROP TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
DROP TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging
DROP TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
```

It is a bit lengthy, but I don't know how else to explain it. I hope what I want makes sense and I don't get penalized too much...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got the answer! I am not sure if this would ever help any one, but I am posting just in case it could:

```
DECLARE @DealerType as VarChar(20)
DECLARE @FilePath as Varchar(1000)
DECLARE @TotalRecords as INT
DECLARE @RecordCount AS INT
DECLARE @DecimalIndex as INT


SET @DealerType = 'ClientName'
SET @FilePath = 'C:\Client Files\Client\AP\2018-07-17\AP-XP0006_MULTI.txt'
DECLARE @UnitPurchasePriceexVAT As Varchar(11)
DECLARE @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT as Varchar(11)
DECLARE @TextToChange As Varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ExchangeRate as Decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @RetailePriceValue as Decimal(18,4)
SET @ExchangeRate = (SELECT CalcValue FROM CalculationValues WHERE CalcName = 'Exchange Rate')
SET @RetailePriceValue = (SELECT CalcValue FROM CalculationValues WHERE CalcName = 'Retail Price Value')

CREATE TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
(Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

DECLARE @SQL as Varchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'bulk insert #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
from ''' + @FilePath + ''' 
with (fieldterminator = ''\t'', rowterminator = ''0x0a'')'

EXEC (@SQL)

CREATE TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging
(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

 CREATE TABLE SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
(Text Varchar(MAX) NULL)

INSERT INTO #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging(Text)
SELECT Text FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp

SET @TotalRecords = (SELECT COUNT(TEXT) FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging)
SET @RecordCount = 1

WHILE (@RecordCount <= @TotalRecords)
BEGIN
    SET @TextToChange = (SELECT Text FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging WHERE ID = @RecordCount)

    SET @UnitPurchasePriceexVAT = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,89,11))
    SET @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT = CAST((((CAST(@UnitPurchasePriceexVAT as decimal(11,2))/100) * @ExchangeRate * 100) * @RetailePriceValue)*100 as varchar)
    SET @DecimalIndex = CHARINDEX('.',@NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT,1)
    SET @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT = STUFF(@NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(CAST(@NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT as Varchar),@DecimalIndex,7), @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT), 
                        LEN(SUBSTRING(CAST(@NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT as Varchar),@DecimalIndex,7)), 
                        '')

    SET @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT = REPLICATE('0',11-LEN(@NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT)) + @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT
    SET @TextToChange = STUFF(@TextToChange, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11), @TextToChange), LEN(SUBSTRING(@TextToChange,100,11)), @NewUnitSellingPriceExVAT)

    INSERT INTO SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
    SELECT @TextToChange

    SET @RecordCount = @RecordCount + 1
END

SELECT * FROM SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
SELECT * FROM #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
DROP TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp
DROP TABLE #SparePartsPriceList_Temp_staging
DROP TABLE SparePartsPriceList_Temp_Export
```